# How to dynamically load a CSS file avoiding navigator cache

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've usually loaded CSS files with PHP by adding a GET variable that changes each time. For example the value of the microtime

But I need to dynamically load a CSS file avoiding navigator cache for see the continuous changes making in production development.

```
<?php echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myFile.css?v='.round(microtime(true)).'"></script>';?>
```

Comment: _Side note:_ You have a rouge `</script>` in the end that doesn't belong there.

Comment: I don't get the question. If you want to make sure the css isn't cached, the posted code should already be doing that? If you want it to be cached until it gets a new version, then you can add proper version numbers when you release a new css version (this can be done automatically in many different ways, depending our your release pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will need to load a dynamic file name as well.
It is possible to do it without PHP like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="" id="myCSS">

<script>     
  var microTime = Date.now();   
  var myVar = "myCSSFile";
  var myUrl = myVar+'.css' + '?v=' + microTime;

  myCSS.href= myUrl;
</script>
```